# How to get rid of skype extension on mozilla firefox browser opened from cfx?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I am new to firefox add-on development. When I open Mozilla browser from command line using "cfx run" to test my Add-on, it comes with a skype extension on it, which prints lot of error / log messages on console. Its hard to debug my log statements from them. How do I get rid of this Skype extension ?

Here is the error messages I get on console every time I run "cfx run".
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just uninstalled the skype On-click extension from programs. it worked.